# Does it make sense to show the careers link on every stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Hello,
seeing the "careers" link in Seasoned Advice pointing to careers.stackoverflow.com, it seems to me that it is a bit off-topic.

Shouldn't it be shown only on IT-related Stack Exchange sites?

Or shouldn't an in-topic careers site be built for the macro-areas for which it makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea, but I think there is the critical mass needed to create other careers sites at this time.

Also, I think it is ok to show careers links in non IT related Stack Exchange sites, because users in these sites might still be interested.  (Although the numbers would not be large, but I assume there are users in several of the smaller Stack Exchange sites that might not even know about StackOverflow or at least not careers.)

Comment: I believe that users might be interested because I *suppose* that most *.stackexchange users have a huge intersection with stackoverflow users. But what will happen when those communities will grow independently? Would you be happy if the careers link in stackoverflow pointed to careers for cooks? ;)

Comment: @Andrea,  I agree, I just think the other communities aren't large enough yet to justify separate sites.